# Stability of Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions for numerical solution of differential equations for non-linear problems.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-analysis

I am wondering if someone have experience about the numerical stability of boundary conditions.
I have a finite element problem (non-linear) in elasticity solving with Newton-raphson algorithm and the solution using Dirichlet (displacement) boundary conditions is more stable (more steps can be reached) when compared to Neumann boundary conditions (forces) ... Does someone have any experience with this that could provide a good reference for this fact?
Thank you a lot in advance.